# Bulma: trying to make navbar with two rows, where in mobile the search input from first row move to second row

Tags: css, navbar, bulma

I'm trying to make navbar with two rows: the first row is for secondary menu, the second row is for primary menu. I'm fairly new to Bulma and looking for solution isn't as easy as Bootstrap.

Here is my fiddle (HTML structure) so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/wck1hj9r/4/

```
<div class="navbar nav-secondary" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
            Part of Larger Holding
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">

    </div>

    <div class="navbar-end">
      <a class="navbar-item">
              Menu 1
            </a>
      <a class="navbar-item">
              Menu 2
            </a>

      <div class="navbar-item field">
         <p class="control has-icons-right">
           <input class="input" type="search" placeholder="Search...">
                     <span class="icon is-small is-right">
                     </span>
         </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- nav -->

<nav class="navbar nav-primary" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
            <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
        </a>

    <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
  </div>

  <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">

    </div>

    <div class="navbar-end">
      <a class="navbar-item">
              About
            </a>

            <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
        <a class="navbar-link">
                Team
              </a>

        <div class="navbar-dropdown">
          <a class="navbar-item">
                  Management
                    </a>
          <a class="navbar-item">
                  Experts
                    </a>
          <hr class="navbar-divider">
          <a class="navbar-item">
                  Apply!
                    </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="navbar-item">
              Articles
            </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

As can be seen, my solution so far is to make two Bulma navbars.

Then I want to make the mobile layout to look something like this. The search input is hidden, and a search iconn appears on the second row. The links in second row is hidden and a burger menu appears instead. Meanwhile, the links in first row remains visible.

[image]

My question perhaps is two-fold:

- I'm not sure with this HTML structure, as it seemed to be redundant? How would I best structure it?
- In line with the structure, how should I make it so the mobile layout appears as I explained?

Any guidelines how to do it?

Comment: after user touches the search icon how would the search box appear in mobile view? do you have to use the same search box in the top navbar or is it possible to have two text boxes?

Comment: It's possible to have two inputs, though I'm still wondering if it would be semantically fine (can be easily moved with JS though I guess?).

Comment: yes it can be moved but its not good practice and it might lose some functionalities after u move it

Comment: Hmm. How would it be done with two inputs then?

Answer (score 1):

Many things happening here! So, if I understand, you want to navbar burger to open up to two navbar items, correct?

**1)** First, I see that your `navbar-end` only comes up to before your navbar items. You want that *after* your items.

Example from Bulma:

```
<div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
  <div class="navbar-start">
    <a class="navbar-item">
    Home
    </a>

    <a class="navbar-item">
    Documentation
    </a>

    <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
      <a class="navbar-link">
      More
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-dropdown">
        <a class="navbar-item">
        About
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-item">
        Jobs
        </a>
        <a class="navbar-item">
        Contact
        </a>
        <hr class="navbar-divider">
        <a class="navbar-item">
        Report an issue
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="navbar-end">
```

**2)** NavBar - Here's a piece from Bulma's documentation:

```
<a role="button" class="navbar-burger" data-target="nav-menu" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

Be sure to leave in the three `<span>` tags - those become the three lines of the burger.

**3)** Then, here's the really cool part - to actually get the behaviour of the navbar to toggle on click, you need to add some JS as specified in the section of documentation after the "NavBar Menu" topic (the blue section called "JavaScript Toggle": https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/ . There's a couple ways to create the JS for the functionality but the docs works just as well as the way I wrote it. Be sure to add the JS between `<script>` tags in your main HTML file!

Hope this helps! Read the section of Bulma docs I linked in this answer. They really explain it well it terms of using modifiers to help with your regular HTML code!